# How to hide footer layout on a particular page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my view page, I want to hide the footer partial that is defined in my application.html.erb, how can I do this?

what options do I have to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest/quickest way would probably be to define a conditional:

```
<%= render "layouts/footer" unless @skip_footer %>
```

and then set the variable as necessary in your actions:

```
def non_footer_action
  do_stuff
  @skip_footer = true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, `CSS` solution is the closest to the conventional one:

`app/controllers/resources_controller.rb`

```
class ResourcesController < ApplicationController
  def action
    # ...
  end
end
```

`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<body class="<%= "#{controller_path} #{action_name}" %>">
  <!-- ... -->
  <footer></footer>
</body>
```

`app/assets/stylesheets/resources.css.scss`

```
body.resources {

  // Hide footer for certain views

  &.action footer {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

You may also want to use separate layout for «footerless» actions, albeit *one* element is not good enough reason for another layout.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is 'show.html.erb' you can do the following:

```
<% unless action_name == "show" %>
   <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is quite simple and effective