# I want to eliminate header or footer from some of the pages in my rails rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working in rails project. I created a header and footer and added to all pages in layouts/application.html.erb file. Now I want to remove it from a particular page.

Comment: Just found the best answer in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131073/how-to-hide-footer-layout-on-a-particular-page/65418059#65418059

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each page of a rails app is an `action` nested inside a `controller`.

You can see the current `controller_name` and `action_name` by adding the below to a view:

```
<%= controller_name %>
<%= action_name %>
```

To not render `header` or a `footer` for a specific page (`controller` or `action` or both) you can make the rendering **conditional**:

application.html.erb

```
<body>
  <% unless controller_name = "static_pages" %>
    <%= render "layouts/header" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
  <% unless action_name = "landing_page" %>
    <%= render "layouts/footer" %>
  <% end %>
</body>
```

Alternatively as a more sophisticated approach you can create a separate layout file for a specific controller: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#finding-layouts